# Spark Jobs filling up the disk at SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS location

Tags: apache-spark

spark jobs are filling up the disk within a short amount of time (< 10 mins). I have a disk space of 10GB and it is getting full at SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS location. In my case SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS is set to /usr/local/spark/temp.

There are lot of files like this input-0-1489072623600 and each file is somewhere between 3MB-8MB.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS is used for rdd cache(disk) and shuffle data. You should check the storage details whether how much data is cached(disk) and if any shuffle operations during your job.

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: I don't see anything on that tab. Btw I dont use any distributed storage

Comment: If you are not caching any data to disk, check the size of your temp folder, most probably shuffle is using all the space.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by caching to disk? Yes my temp folder takes all the disk space. So what is the reason behind this? And how should I fix it?

Comment: AS @hemantsingh said, either you have a large shuffle, the verbosity of your logs is too high for the space available or you are printing stuff that should not (like a sysout in a loop).